# How to find an application is running or not with more than one different versions thru c#?

Tags: c#, windows

I need to find that an application is running or not and also need to find its version. Based on that I can further write codes. So first I need to find whether the program is running or not and have to find its version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically to find any application on your computer you will use the `Process` class.

To find if an app is running on the computer :

```
public bool isRunning(string appName) 
{
     return Process.GetProcessesByName(appName) > 0;
}
```

Then to get its version you do

```
Process.GetProcessesByName(appName)[0].MainModule.FileVersionInfo;
```